# How to insert HLS video link

Tags: asp.net, html, video, tags, http-live-streaming

I have an `HLS` link from Vimeo which I want to put into an `html5` video tag.

This is the link: http://player.vimeo.com/external/123834994.m3u8?p=high,standard,mobile&s=53a796101334e99bff44f62f9e7a28df

This is the video tag:

```
<video autoplay muted loop class="bgvid" id="HomeVideoBig">
    <source src="http://player.vimeo.com/external/123834994.hd.mp4?s=8cd812ab0db3a9ce0d256814f9e6dcd8&profile_id=113" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

How should I do this?
I am using asp.net.
I want it to work properly on all browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the provided link as `src` and `application/x-mpegURL` or
`vnd.apple.mpegURL` for type.

Please note that `HLS` is not supported natively on all browsers/devices. On desktop only Safari 6+ has native HLS support. You'll have to use a player which offers Flash fallback. Some players that will work are:

- paid: [JWPlayer](http://www.jwplayer.com/) (HLS needs Premium), [Flowplayer](https://flowplayer.org/)
- open-source: [Clappr](https://github.com/clappr/clappr)

See more: [HLS Device Compatibility](http://www.encoding.com/http-live-streaming-hls/#Device_and_OS_Compatibility)